# Can we integrate a vnet to an azure container registry by passing the vnet id in the ARM template?

Tags: azure, azure-rm-template, azure-container-registry, vnet

```
"networkRuleSet":{
            "defaultAction": "[if(equals(parameters('networkRuleSetStatus'), 'Enabled'), 'Deny', 'Allow')]",
            "virtualNetworkRules":[{
              "action": "Allow",
              "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets', parameters('existingVnetName'), parameters('existingSubnetName'))]"
          }],
            "copy":[{
              "name":"ipRules",
              "count":"[length(parameters('ip'))]",
              "input":{
              "action": "Allow",
              "value": "[parameters('ip') [copyIndex('ipRules')]]"
              }
            }]
          },
```

The above lines are part of the ARM to pass the vnetid in the network section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to integrate a vnet to the Azure container registry and what you did is right. But there is one thing you may miss. The thing is when you want to allow a subnet to access the container registry, you need to enable the private endpoint for the container registry in that subnet. The example CLI command [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-vnet#add-a-service-endpoint-to-a-subnet):

```
az network vnet subnet update \
  --name myDockerVMSubnet \
  --vnet-name myDockerVMVNET \
  --resource-group myResourceGroup \
  --service-endpoints Microsoft.ContainerRegistry
```

After this action, then you can add the network rule through the template as you showed.

Comment: Okay ..Thank you ! but could you please tell me how to check if the vnet is integrated with the container registry after the ARM deployment as I don't see a tab in portal. TIA  @charles-xu

Comment: appreciate the quick help @CharlesXu

Comment: @twinklehema Sure. You can use the command, for example, CLI command `az acr show -n acrName--query networkRuleSet.virtualNetworkRules` to check the subnet resource id.

Comment: but this still shows null  "virtualNetworkRules": [] in the export template and with the above command also.

Comment: vnet id is not being passed

Comment: @twinklehema It shows the subnet id, when you know the subnet id, you also know the vnet id, doesn't it?

Comment: unrecognized arguments: networkRuleSet.virtualNetworkRules  it throws this error not showing any id

Comment: @twinklehema Can you share the screenshot about the command you use?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231693/discussion-between-twinkle-hema-and-charles-xu).

Comment: there is an error in passing the resource id

Comment: @twinklehema What is that? Share the details of the error.